# How do I create an if statement in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have a flutter app that uses a real time database through Firebase.  I know what I want to do but am so new to this that I am unsure of myself.

When a person scans the barcode, it shows up as a button.  When they search for that item, it returns the proper attributes listed in the database.  Great.

But what happens when the item isn't in the database?  I want to create an if statement that is something like this in pseudocode:

Search for UPC:
If search results in null run "add barcode" method.
Create text inputs for all data required to add to DB.
If search results in hit, display data.
Run method that displays data

Comment: Post you code here

Comment: I do not have code yet.  Would it be possible to use a try catch?  Try and if successful post the results and catch run another method so users can input data?